# Adobe Flex in an email?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

Is it possible to host a very basic trust, Adobe Flex application in an email?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Not even the simplies Flash movie.

Comment: Current e-mail protocols restrict anything beyond html and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically possible to do something like this, but modern email clients are extremely sensitive to anything that could be used for malicious purposes and Adobe Flex would count as "executable code".

If you're looking for a guide on what you can and can't use in email clients, Campaign Monitor has a good overview of [CSS for Email](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Otherwise, I think the best that you'll be able to do is email out a link to a page that had the Flex app embedded in it.